# Selecting rows where datetime column is a certain day

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to write a SQLite query in Android where I select all rows from a table where the day component of the datetime column (stored as ISO 8601 strings) equals a given day. Basically, I want to select all rows with a certain date, disregarding the time.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
select * from table_name where day=desired_day;
```

So this code:

```
database.query("table_name", null, "day like ?",new String[]{"____-__-daynumber%"}, null, null, null, null);
```

Checkout this [documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php) to see how I figured out that sql regex to use. This regex allows for any year and any month. If you want only a specific day in a specific month in a specific year do:

```
database.query("table_name", null, "day like ?",new String[]{"1983-03-22%"}, null, null, null, null);
```

This would look for the day 03/22/1983

Comment: The column is a datetime, i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS, so using a day, YYYY-MM-DD will not be equal and will return no results -- isn't that correct?

Comment: Edited my response to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has some [date time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). In your case the select could look as follows:

```
select * from table where date(your_date_time_column) = iso_8601_date_only_value;
```

Comment: Right but `date(your_date_time_column, 'localtime')` might be needed depending on how timezones are being handled.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM test 
        WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', timecol)=strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2008-04-12')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 as start and end times and simply use <= and >= in a raw query such as...

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE the_datetime_column >= '2011-11-15 00:00:00' AND the_datetime_column <= '2011-11-15 23:59:59'
```